# How to make unit tests for methods/events

Tags: c#, asp.net, unit-testing, nunit

I need to make units tests for an ASP.net application. Since i never did it. I was wondering how i could make tests for events(click etc...) or to check what a method is returning...

Do you have some example to share?
Thanks in advance

Comment: [This SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2765884/960195) is very similar and should prove useful.

Answer (score 0):

You could probably get started by reading the [NUnit Quickstart](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=quickStart&r=2.2.10), and if it needs become more ASP.NET specific maybe this [post on NUnit and ASP.NET in particular](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/NUnitUnitTestingOfASPNETPagesBaseClassesControlsAndOtherWidgetryUsingCassiniASPNETWebMatrixVisualStudioWebDeveloper.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

You will find it hard to write unit tests against code behind files as you will eventual come across methods/events which rely for the HttpContext to exist. The HttpContext is a sealed class not inheriting from an interface itself. That makes it impossible to mock.

Given that a valid HttpContext might have to exist (say for example a redirect) you unit test will throw an "Object is not initialized" exception.

Rather than dealing with those issues as they come across you you can make an asp.net application more unit test friendly by applying the Model-View-Presenter (MVP) pattern or similar.
Separating the UI from the business logic and the model.

The idea is to move all your business logic out of the code-behind file into a separate, plain C# class (The Presenter) which you can now also write unit tests against.

You can find more about ASP.NET and MVP here:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc188690.aspx

I'm not saying re-factor all your code to apply MVP, I'm merely suggesting to move the business logic where possible into a separate class which you test against, using MVP as a guideline.

Answer (score 0):

This is one of ASP.NET's big design flaws, and the reason why a lot of new projects are being developed in ASP.NET MVC. As François Wahl says, to make your project more testable, you should move as much of the business logic as you can into a presenter class that you can write unit tests against.

To test your ASP.NET event handlers, you'll really need to target your tests at the UI itself. A tool like [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/) is useful for this. It runs on the client so is completely agnostic to whatever platform you're running on the server. It also comes with a Firefox add-on to help you automate test cases.

Answer (score 0):

you can use tool like 
http://watin.org/

where you can test your asp.net code in following way.

```
[Test]
public void ExampleTest()
{
IE ie = new IE("http://www.google.com"); 

ie.TextField(Find.ByName("q")).TypeText("WatiN"); 
ie.Button(Find.ByValue("Google Search")).Click(); 
Link link = ie.Link(Find.By("href", "http://watin.sourceforge.net/"));

Assert.That(link.Text == "WatiN Home"); 
}
```

To unit test your business classes you can use Nunit and rhino mocks as mocking framework

you can find moq which is other mocking framework you can use at following location.

http://code.google.com/p/moq/

for UI testing you can use Selenium Or codedUI test from visual studio. 
for project structure use MVP or MVC as framework which will provide separation of concerns and you can test your model logic using NUNIT or other unit testing frameworks.